# Passing data to dynamic page in node.js without templating engine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a blogging website with node/express.js and mongodb. Now, I want to view individual blog so I created an endpoint of `'/articles/:id'` so I can only display that particular blog details.

But the problem is **how do I show the blog related information in an html page, how do I send that information to frontend** ? Like I can't even do a `fetch` on the `'/articles/:id'` endpoint because the id would change depending on the specific blog.

One solution you might say is that to use a templating engine but I build the whole thing up till now without templating engine and also I want to know how to do it without a templating engine.

This is my code for individual article. Here I am fetching the blog data from mongodb database and sending it via `res.json`

```
app.get('/articles/:id', (req, res) => {
    ArticleModel.findById(req.params.id).then(article => res.json(article));
});
```

Is it possible to so without any templating engine at first place ?

Answer (score 1):

In my view You have two alternatives :-

-> you can send HTML code using res.send like this.

```
app.get('/articles/:id', (req, res) => {
    const city="Londan";
    const country="England";
    const temp=24;
    res.send("<h1>Hello, The temperature in "+city+","+country+" is "+temp+"</h1>");
});
```

-> Use a library which replaces template engine or in other words which t can do HTML and DOM manipulation like jsdom, cheerio, plates.(haven't tried this personally) because I have always use template engine because it helps me to separate service side code and client side code.
This answer talks in more details about https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114041/13126651.

But my recommendations would be to use template engine for it will simplify your most of the work, there are lof of great options like ejs and my personal favourite is handlebars.

Comment: Okay so I have to use templating engine to do complex tasks in short, because sending data with `res.send` seems cumbersome. Still if someone has a better solution they are welcomed here

Comment: But you can try sending dynamic data using res.send( ''html tags") like i have shown in the example using variables, if it helped you in any way, you can accept the answer so that it may help others in the future

Comment: Thats what I said sending data with `res.send("html tags")` would be very time consuming and hard at the same time. And the thing about templates i knew already I was expecting for a solution better than `res.send` .**No offence but I upvoted your answer because it is useful**. I did no accept your answer because I was searching for a better alternative than `res.send`.

Comment: understood, try other libraries like jsdom or cheerio